# Google spreadsheetの内容を外部のhtml(wikidot)に記述する

Tags: javascript, html, google-spreadsheet

初心者です

外部のhtml上(wikidot)に何らかの方法でGoogle spreadsheetの内容(例えばA1等)を
pタグの中に入れて、Google spreadsheetの内容の変更に応じて随時更新できるようなことは可能でしょうか？
[同様の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48968/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%81%AEhtml%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)

可能であればご教授いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wikidot は JavaScript が使えるので、[質問文で参照されている Q&A](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48968/19110) のように API エンドポイントを用意することで実現できそうです。

※HTML block の中に `<script>` タグを入れることができます
https://www.wikidot.com/doc-wiki-syntax:html-blocks
http://community.wikidot.com/forum/t-464691/is-there-a-way-to-include-a-runnable-piece-of-javascript

Comment: なるほど…ありがとうございます。
それと、素人質問で本当に申し訳ないのですが、
件の質問の所の最終行
> document.getElementById(targetID).innerText = text;
は書き換えを行っているのでしょうか？
少々そこの動作が分からず手間取っております。

Comment: いえいえ、お気になさらず、ここは質問をするサイトですので =)　件の行ですが、はい、書き換えを行っています。おそらく [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) が何であるかを確認していただければ分かるのではないかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
無事、反映することが出来ました。
もう一つだけよろしいでしょうか…？

これは、1つしかセルの内容を保持できないのですが、複数セルを外部にもっていく場合はどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 複数セルの場合、そのデータがどういう風に使われるのかによって設計が変わりそうです。API エンドポイントを複数設置する方法もありますし、[`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange\(Integer,Integer\)) の時点で複数取得しておいて JavaScript 側で分解する方法もあります。

Comment: 成程…、その方法で処理が可能なのですね。ありがとうございます。