# GASでの2次配列からjsonに変換し、そのjsonデータを外部のhtmlにAPIで通してそのhtml内でテーブルにしたい。

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63000/google-spreadsheet%e3%81%ae%e5%86%85%e5%ae%b9%e3%82%92%e5%a4%96%e9%83%a8%e3%81%aehtmlwikidot%e3%81%ab%e8%a8%98%e8%bf%b0%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)にて以前,Wikidotの方にGASからAPIを使用して内容を記述する方法をお教えいただいたのですが、それ等を使って実現することができないと考え、
スプレッドシートの内容を配列にするところまではできたのですが、その配列からjsonに変換することが出来ずにいます。
jsonに変換ができたならば、

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(dataArray))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

GASの方でAPIにして
外部htmlの方でFetch APIでjsonデータを取得できると考えております。
そのjsonデータを

```
 translater_name title                           Reservation_date   End_date          User_UNIX User_ID
 XXXXXXXXXXXXX   http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx 29 Feb 2020 15:00  29 Feb 2020 15:00 XXXXXX    111111
```

というふうにテーブルにしたいと思っています。
お手すきの際に可能であれば、お答えいただければ幸甚です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

以下、GASのcode

```
function doGet() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Reservation");

  var dataArray = convSheet(sheet);

  //dataをJsonに変換し、新規シート出力
 }

//data（配列）へ変換関数
 function convSheet(sheet) {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Reservation");
  //内容開始行番号
  var rowIndex=2;
  //列開始行番号
  var colStartIndex = 1;
  //行番号
  var rowNum = 1;
  //最初行領域
  var lastclomn =sheet.getLastColumn();

  var firstRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6);
   Logger.log('firstRange:'+JSON.stringify(firstRange));
  var firstRowValues = firstRange.getValues();
   Logger.log('firstRowValues:'+JSON.stringify(firstRowValues));
  //項目情報取得
  var titleColumns = firstRowValues[0];
  Logger.log('titleColumns: '+titleColumns);

  var index_translater_name = titleColumns.indexOf('translater_name');
  var index_title = titleColumns.indexOf('title');
  var index_Reservation_date = titleColumns.indexOf('Reservation_date');
  var index_End_date = titleColumns.indexOf('End_date');
  var index_User_UNIX = titleColumns.indexOf('User_UNIX');
  var index_User_ID = titleColumns.indexOf('User_ID');
   Logger.log('index_translater_name: '+index_translater_name+'  '+'index_title: '+index_title+'  '+'index_Reservation_date: '+index_Reservation_date+'  ' +'index_End_date: '+index_End_date+'  '+'index_User_UNIX: '+index_User_UNIX+'  '+'index_User_ID:'+index_User_ID);
  var exceptIndexArray =[index_translater_name,index_title,index_Reservation_date,index_End_date,index_User_UNIX,index_User_ID];
  Logger.log('exceptIndexArray: '+exceptIndexArray);

  //最後の行番号
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   Logger.log('lastRow:'+JSON.stringify(lastRow));
  //内容情報取得配列
  var rowValues = [];
  //内容取得
  for(rowIndex; rowIndex<=lastRow; rowIndex++) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, colStartIndex, rowNum, 6);
    var values = range.getValues();
    //内容情報にPUSH
    rowValues.push(values[0]);
  }
   Logger.log('rowValues:'+JSON.stringify(rowValues));


  //Json形式配列
  var dataArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i<rowValues.length; i++) {
    //内容の行情報
    var line = rowValues[i];
    //JsonObject
    var json = new Object();

    //残りJson作成
    for(var j=0; j<titleColumns.length; j++) {      
        json[titleColumns[j]] = line[j];
    }
    //data格納
    dataArray.push(json);
  }
  //「dataArray」ログ確認
  Logger.log(dataArray);
  return dataArray;
 }

function doGetjson(request) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(dataArray))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

---

GAScode最終部分のloger.log(dataArray)の出力内容

```
[{User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, {User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, {User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, {User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, {User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, {User_UNIX=XXXXXX, translater_name=xxxxxxx, End_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, title=http://www.XXX.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx, Reservation_date=29 Feb 2020 15:00, User_ID=1111111}, ]
```

---

wikidot側のsource

```
[[html]]
<div id="json_disp"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
const url ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec"
 fetch('url', {
   method: 'GET'
 }).then(function (response) {
   return response.json();
 }).then(function (myjson) {

//3:json形式のデータをWebページに出力する
  makeTable(myjson);
});

function makeTable(jsonlist) {
  var table_wrap = document.getElementById("json_disp");
  var table = "<table>";
  table += "<th>translater_name</th><th>title</th><th>Reservation_date</th><th>End_date</th><th>user_unix</th>";
  //------------
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonlist.length; i++) {
    var linedata = jsonlist[0];
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>" + jsonlist[i].translater_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonlist[i].title + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonlist[i].Reservation_date + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonlist[i].End_date + "</td>" + "<td><span class=¥"printuser avatarhover¥"><a href=¥"http://www.wikidot.com/user:info/" + jsonlist[i].User_UNIX+ "¥"><img class=¥"small¥" src=¥"http://www.wikidot.com/avatar.php?userid="+ jsonlist[i].User_ID +"¥" alt=¥""+jsonlist[i].User_UNIX+"¥" style=¥"background-image:url(http://www.wikidot.com/userkarma.php?u="+jsonlist[i].User_ID+")¥"></a><a href=¥"http://www.wikidot.com/user:info/"+jsonlist[i].User_UNIX+"¥">"+jsonlist[i].User_UNIX+"</a></span></td>";
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  //-----------
  table += "</table>";
  //要素に追加
  table_wrap.innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

[[/html]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あまりよく分かっていませんが、簡単に見た感じ数や文字列のみの配列 `rowValues`（あるいは Object の配列 `dataArray`？）を JSON にするのであれば、単に `{ data: rowValues }` のように、唯一の要素がその配列であるような JSON を作れば良いのではないかと思いました。

https://www.json.org/json-ja.html

Comment: 成程,,,ありがとうございます。リンクのページを見ながら作っていこうと思います。